# Save R data frame into file and by which command to read it?

Tags: r

*Please, go to the bottom to read from bottom up. I created MWE to show what I want, hard to explain. This question has probably about 5-20 chars answer.*

I want to access df from a file like on console with `df$s1` way:

```
> data.frame(s1=1:10,s2=1:10)->a
> a$s1
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

I have forgot the command to do that:

```
> system('Rscript t.r > tt')
> system('cat tt')
   s1 s2
1   1  1
2   2  2
3   3  3
4   4  4
5   5  5
6   6  6
7   7  7
8   8  8
9   9  9
10 10 10
> system('cat t.r')
print(data.frame(s1=1:10,s2=1:10))
```

by which command can I read the R df? Look

```
> read.csv('tt')
      s1.s2
1  1   1  1
2  2   2  2
3  3   3  3
4  4   4  4
5  5   5  5
6  6   6  6
7  7   7  7
8  8   8  8
9  9   9  9
10 10 10 10
> read.csv('tt')->b
> b$s1     # WON't work! By which command it works?
```

Comment: `tt` isn't comma-delimited.  Use `read.table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
a <- data.frame(s1=1:10, s2=1:10)
write.table(a, 'tt', col.names = TRUE)
b <- read.table('tt', header = T)
b$s2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you the baroque method first and then the regular method.

```
read.table(text= system('cat tt'), header=TRUE)
```

It appears your file has no commas so using read.csv isn't very sensible.

```
b <- read.table(file='tt', header=TRUE)
b$s1
```